# Using selenium webdriver to upload a file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build some automated test for a mailbox application and I'm trying to attach a file. I've read all the documentation from previous post and was able to come up with this:

```
public void I_attach_a_file_that_exceeds_the_limit() throws Throwable {

    WebElement attachFile = driver.findElement(By.id("attachment"));
    File f = new File("C:\\coop-provider-swm-specs\\src\\test\\resources\\attachments\\20481kb.txt");
    attachFile.sendKeys(f.getCanonicalPath());

}
```

The problem with this is that the file that it attaches is not the real file. The file that is attached is blank (not sure how that works). The file that I need to attach is a big file and I need to do this in order the authenticate that the user does not exceed the limit for attachments that is allowed.

Comment: What happens when you try generating this code by recording a macro?

Comment: Why did you create the File object if you only needed the path?

Comment: admdrew, these automated tests are developed using java for the selenium webdriver, I don't believe recording a macro will apply (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: BarbiePylon the file object was to point to the new file, but I believe I understand where you are coming from, feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Well, if you're pointing to a file that is already on the file system then it doesn't seem like you need to create a new File especially if you're just grabbing the path anyway. Just put the path in the sendKeys() method...If you're creating a new File period then you need to write something to it first otherwise it's going to be blank.

Comment: I may have been wrong/misleading...I actually don't know what would happen if you tried to attach a file that didn't exist in this scenario. The file is real though, correct? :)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
attachFile.sendKeys(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

To:

```
attachFile.sendKeys(f.getCanonicalPath()).submit();
```

Comment: I was able to attach the file using this line: attachFile.sendKeys("C:\\workspace-ecweb\\coop-provider-swm-specs\\src\\main\\resources\\attachments\\20481kb.txt"); but I was trying to resolve a relative path and what you suggested above isn't working.

Comment: So why don't you simply use `getAbsolutePath` instead of `getCanonicalPath` then?

Comment: The tests will be distributed to other users on a server who will not necessarily have a c:// drive.

Comment: Calling `getAbsolutePath` will just yield a different path in that case, so where is the problem then?